# How to install a .vsix

Tags: visual-studio

I recently downloaded a theme for visual studio 2012 and the file ends in a .vsix. I check on the internet but I couldn't find the program names Vsix Installer. Could someone tell me how I can install the .vsix file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You just double click on the `.vsix` file and it will install.

Alternatively you could install it from VS Extension Manager (Tools->Extension Manager)

Comment: It says that I need to select a program in order to run it.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio installed you should already have the necessary association. Alternatively you could install it from VS Extension Manager (Tools->Extension Manger)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but the association is :/Program Files (86)/Microsoft Visual Studio /Common7/IDE/VSIXInstaller.exe

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Should be accepted answer. Tools -> Extension manager does not allow you to select .vsix file! Assosiation is broken in VS2017.

Comment: It was helpful. Re-associating with VSIXInstaller.exe worked. Thanks. Looks like installing and uninstalling the VS2017 RC broke the association.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 Community I do not see "Extension Manager", but it looks like its been messed up since February as I have been seeing things posted today and I also found this here [How Do you Install a visual studio 2017 extention vsix from an msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271047/how-do-you-install-a-visual-studio-2017-extension-vsix-from-an-msi)

Answer (score 0):

Open in VisualStudio the folder that contain the "nameFile.vsix" file. File, Open Folder..., click right in the "nameFile.vsix" into de VisualStudio, and click in install extension VSIX. It is not necessary use an extension to intall a .vsix file.